# divi builder in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, divi

I am new to divi builder.

The website is built by another person and it has an issue that I would need to fix.

My question is how and where would I find this line of code:

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Product">
<ul><li>1×  <span itemprop="name">SW-RAF1800</span> (25W fan)</li></ul></div>
```

I am unable to find the "itemscope", "itemtype", and "itemprop" codes in the backend of  the wordpress page.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: That is very little info to help you. We would need some more detail. What you find inside the HTML of your page could be just an output of divi builder, some 3rd party plugin or even some js code. Add some more details

Comment: Hi Diego, I have found the code and fixed it. Thank you for your reply anyway.